# Virtual Chocolatey Repository Does Not Get Latest Packages From Remote

Tags: nuget, artifactory, chocolatey

I have a virtual chocolatey repository that maps a local and a remote repo (in that order). I've configured my chocolatey sources to have only this virtual repo.

Currently, I have v0.46 choco package of `hugo` installed. When I do `choco upgrade hugo`, I get a message saying

`hugo v0.46 is newer than the most recent. You must be smarter than the average bear...`

If I switch chocolatey sources to point to the remote repo instead, doing `choco upgrade hugo` installs v0.53 as I would expect.

Also, if I run `choco list hugo` while pointing to the virtual repo only, I see hugo package has 0.53.

So it seems like there's something weird with the virtual repo.

Running Artifactory 6.5.3.

Has anyone resolved issues like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are running into the issue reported here: [RTFACT-17889](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-17889).

As you said, working directly against the remote seems to work.